# htaccess rewrite one url on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, path

How is possible in .htaccess to make from subdomain

`example.domain.com/gallery/index.html`
into `example.domain.com/gallery/`

Comment: By implementing a rewrite rule for that request URL. You will find endless examples for that online.

Comment: Did alot of examples and i got 500 error

Comment: OK, then please show one or two of those examples and please add what entry you received in your http servers error log file.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^gallery/([A-Za-z]+)/$ /gallery/index/$1.html [L]`

Comment: Well, the immediate approach would be something like `RewriteRule ^/?gallery/index\.html$ /gallery/ [END]`. But that _might_ lead to an endless rewriting loop, depending on your setup which we do not know.

Comment: There is just one page example.example.com/gallery/index.html and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to say with your last comment to the question. The rule I posted rewrites exactly one URL. But maybe you are looking for the opposite redirection, I just realize, so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?gallery/index\.html$ /gallery/ [R=301]
RewriteRule /?gallery/?$ /gallery/index.html [END]
```

This redirects clients requesting `/gallery/indx.html` but still delivers the local file `/gallery/index.html` when requesting `/gallery`.